# OpenXML Spread sheet style always set to the first font

Tags: c#, openxml

I am using C#.net with OpenXML for creating a spread sheet. I create few fonts and added to the style sheet . Th problem is I can't switch to the second font.
private Cell CreateCell(string text, uint styleIndex)
{
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.StyleIndex = styleIndex;

```
            cell.DataType = ResolveCellDataTypeOnValue(text);
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(text);
            return cell;
        }

 using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create("somefile.xls", SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
                {
                    WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
                    workbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();
                    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();

                    WorkbookStylesPart sp = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
                    sp.Stylesheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Stylesheet();
                    Stylesheet stylesheet = sp.Stylesheet;
                    stylesheet.Fonts = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fonts();                     

                    Font font = new Font(new FontSize() { Val = 11 }, new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Color() { Rgb = HexBinaryValue.FromString("4b53cb") }, new Bold());


                    Font font2 = new Font(new FontSize() { Val = 15 }, new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Color() { Rgb = HexBinaryValue.FromString("c93653") }, new Italic());
                    stylesheet.Fonts.Append(font);

                    stylesheet.Fonts.Append(font2);

                    stylesheet.Save();

                    SheetData sheetData = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData();

                    MergeCells mergeCells = new MergeCells();                  

                    workRow.Append(CreateCell("Some text", (UInt32Value)2U));                    

                    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);
                    worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();                
                    Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
                    Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "Trial" };
                   sheets.Append(sheet);
                    workbookPart.Workbook.Save();

                }
```

Comment: The framework I understand from here takes the first record added by default. What is the logic in creating two fonts and adding them?

Comment: second for another cell. I have also problem with fills... could you demonstrate... thank you